# Reactjs, using material UI: Invalid hook call error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I´m pretty new to React, and I tried using a component from Material UI. I installed it locally to my project with npm install, and then imported the components I wanted into my project. But when I run start, I get:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   ▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
   Module.
   src/index.js:7

I´ve been researching and saw that this is a pretty common error that a lot of people have, but I´ve tried all of the solutions proposed and none seemed to work. Someone suggested this may be happening because I have many copies of React, and after running npm ls react I got this:
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EgtN.png). Although I have many copies of react, I looked up that deduped means de duplicated, so I concluded this was not the source of the problem.
As soon as I delete the  component, the project runs without any issues. Please if someone could solve my problem I would really appreciate it.

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
```

Faq.js:

```
const Faq = (props) =>{

        return (
            <Accordion>
                <Accordion>
                    <AccordionSummary
                    
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                    >
                    <p>Pregunta1</p>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                    <p>HOLAA</p>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
                <Accordion>
                    <AccordionSummary
                    
                    aria-controls="panel2a-content"
                    id="panel2a-header"
                    >
                    <p>Pregunta2</p>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                   <p>Holaaaa</p>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
            </Accordion>
        )
    }
    
    export default Faq;
```

MainCard.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
import Faq from './Faq'


const MainCard = () =>{

    return(
        <div className="cardcontainer">
            <div className="nosotros">
                <div className="titulosnosotros">
                    <h1 className="titulo">Estudio sobre el diario <br />pionero de la transformación digital</h1>
                    <h2 className="subtitulo">¿Querés concoer más acerca de <br /> su reinvención?</h2>
                    <button className="download">¡Descargue aquí!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="informacion">
                <ul className="informacionlist"> 
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/cliente.png" />
                        <p className="informacion-texto">Cliente siempre en el centro</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/multiplataforma.png" />
                        <p className="informacion-texto">Más que un diario, una multiplataforma</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/barreras.png" />
                        <p className="informacion-texto">Atravesando barreras en la era digital</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="transformacion">
                <h3 className="titulo-transformacion">Un diario que supo adaptarse</h3>
                <img className="fotodiario" src="./images/diario.jpg" />
                <h4 className="subtitulo-informacion">Desde 1869 hasta el presente digital</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="comentarios informacion">
            <h3 className="titulo-comentarios titulo-transformacion">Comentarios</h3>
            <ul className="informacionlist"> 
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/icono.png" />
                        <p className="comentarios-texto">"¡Muy interesante!"</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/icono.png" />
                        <p className="comentarios-texto">"No puedo parar de leer"</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/icono.png" />
                        <p className="comentarios-texto">"Muchas cosas que no sabía"</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="./images/icono.png" />
                        <p className="comentarios-texto">"¡Me encantó!"</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <Faq />
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainCard;
```

App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MainCard from './components/MainCard';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Header from './components/Header';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <MainCard />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "landingpage-lanacion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^7.0.0"
},

  

  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are `react`, `react-dom`, and `@material-ui/core` added as `devDependencies`? Btw, there is no v7.0.0 of [@material-ui/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) at the time of writing.

Comment: Honestly, I´m not exactly sure. I saw one person who had the same issue was able to change it by putting the three in dev dependencies. And you´re right about the version, I had misread it, so I just changed it, thanks!

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) example?

Comment: I built the codebox example and copied all of my files, installed all of the dependencies. But the code works in sandbox. And I don´t understand why it is working here and not in my original project.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm uninstall @material-ui/core
npm uninstall @material-ui/icons
npm uninstall @material-ui/lab
```

Then:

```
npm i @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab
```

Comment: It didin´t work,  but thank  you anyways for answering! I really appreciate it